# Passing Getter to Vuex Action returns null

Tags: vue.js, async-await, graphql, vuex, apollo-client

I'm trying to pass a getter to my async action and it console logs just fine, but the await that calls an apollo mutation keeps seeing it as a null value whereas it just printed a real value to the console...
I'm also using `vuex-persisted-state` to keep the store data alive. So the cartId state is not null by the time the action is performed... hence why it console logs the cartId value correctly.

state:

```js
  cartId: null, //initially null, is set with mounted in another component
```

getters:

```js
  getCartId(state) {
    return state.cartId
  },
```

actions:

```js
  async getCartItems({ commit, getters }) {
    let getCartId = getters.getCartId
    console.log(getCartId) // returns: Z2lkOi8vc2hvcGlmeS9DYXJ0LzBhMDIxNDQ2ODQ0ZDU1MGRhZmZmMWJjZTIzNTBhNDY4
    const { data } = await this.app.apolloProvider.defaultClient.query({
      query: getCart,
      variables() {
        return {
          cartId: getCartId
        }
      },
      skip() {
        return !getCartId
      }
    })
  },
```

Console Error:
`Uncaught (in promise) Error: GraphQL error: Variable $cartId of type ID! was provided invalid value`

GraphQL Response: `Expected value to not be null`

***EDIT:***
The problem seems to lie with how variables are passes to my query

Comment: might be becoz of a delay with the loading of the other component. You are still able to see it on console becoz the value will be updated in the console with the new change. To debug this add a breakpoint on the `console` line and check by hovering on the `getCartId`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed by making `variables` not a function in my await...

```js
async getCartItems({ commit, getters }) {
    const getCartId = await getters.getCartId
    const { data } = await this.app.apolloProvider.defaultClient.query({
      query: getCart,
      variables: {
        cartId: getCartId
      },
      skip() {
        return !getCartId
      }
    })
    if (data.cart) {
      commit('updateCartObj', data.cart)
    } else {
      console.log('getCartItems Error' + data)
    }
  },
```